# Laravel Validating Arrays Select fields

Tags: laravel, validation, select

Laravel easily validates array based form input fields

```
<input name='input_name[0][0]">
<input name='input_name[0][1]">
```

with

```
'input_name.* = 'required',
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#validating-arrays

But how can I **validate array based select fields?**

I have a form where customer info is added, user has to choose the customer's gender and it's possible to add infinite number of customer.

So i have a select for 1 customer:

```
<select name="gender[0]">
<option selected="selected" disabled="disabled" hidden="hidden" value="">Gender</option>
<option value="Male">Male</option>
<option value="Female">Female</option></select>
```

and then

```
<select name="gender[1]">...
<select name="gender[N]">
```

When I set the rule as:

```
'gender.*' => 'required'
```

It doesn't recognize an 'unchoosen' select-box as an error....

But if I update validation rules to:

```
'gender[0]'=>'required'
'gender[1]'=>'required'
'gender[N]'=>'required'
```

It works absolutely fine... (by "it works", I mean that it returns a mistake "Gender field is required").

So, apparently Laravel has some problems with array based select names.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: put it in a loop!

Answer (score 1):

```
public function rules() {
    $rules = [];

    $gender = $this->input('gender');
    foreach ($gender as $index => $item) {
        $rules["gender.{$index}"] = 'required';
    }

    return $rules;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've decided o answer the question myself.

1) **First solution** is to make the first "placeholder" option not disabled (as was in my case, see above - it's because I use LaravelCollective and they have it by default):

```
<select name="gender[0]">
<option selected="selected" hidden="hidden" value="">Gender</option>
<option value="Male">Male</option>
<option value="Female">Female</option></select>
```

When you remove 'disabled' from option-1 of your select then it sends ' ' when posting (*instead of sending nothing with 'disabled'*). So it sends

```
gender[0] = '';
gender[1] = '';
```

etc...

Actually, if you have a lot of `gender[N]` (or maybe other array based selects) I think it's the neatest solution.

2) **Second solution** is provided below by omadonex:

```
public function rules() {
    $rules = [];

    $gender = $this->input('gender');
    foreach ($gender as $index => $item) {
        $rules["gender.{$index}"] = 'required';
    }

    return $rules;
}
```

in this case you'll have a separate rule for every array-based select and it will work (see why in the end of my topicstarter-post). I prefer this solution less than 1st one because you'll have a long list of "gender"-rules if you have a lot of ...

3) **Also I've undertood** why `'gender[0]'=>'required'`
works

and    `'gender.*' => 'required'`
does not

for array based selects like `<select name=gender[0]>`

It's kind of obvious if you think about it: when POSTING select tag with first option (a placeholder) being disabled, as in my example above:

```
<option selected="selected" disabled="disabled" hidden="hidden" value="">Gender</option>
```

the $POST sends nothing....

So if Laravel's validation rule is `'gender[0]'=>'required'` Laravel "thinks": "OKAY, I've received no `"gender[0]"`,  but I know what is required exactly (`"gender[0]"`, of course) . I have to send a mistake because there is no `"gender[0]"`.

But if rule is `'gender.*' => 'required'` and Laravel get's no input of "gender" kind, then it also doesn't know what EXACTLY is required (`'gender.*'` may mean `gender[0]`... `gender [12345]` ... `gender[anything]`). Laravel can't send a mistake, because infinite number of `gender[...]` is missing, so he simply omits it....

PS. If you work with **LaravelCollective forms** of newer versions, they create **placeholder "disabled" by default. Here is a macro to avoid it.**

```
{!! 
        Form::macro('selectNonDisabled', function($value, $placeholder, $array, $disabled=null, $class=null) {
        $select  = "<select class='form-control $class' $disabled name='$value'>";

        $select .= "<option selected='selected' hidden='hidden' value=''>$placeholder</option>";

        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {

        $select .= "<option value='$key'>$value</option>";

        }

        $select .= "</select>";

    return $select;

        });
!!}
```

Comment: You're in my first search, you really solved the problem. Good Job. Thx

Comment: :) you are welcome. Wish you success with your projects:)